# Update de un campo tipo DATE con valor NULL

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito guardar un campo de tipo DATE con un valor NULL;

```html
$mod_date_session = date(Y-m-d,NULL);
```

```html
$sql = "UPDATE document SET date_session = \"$mod_date_session\" WHERE id = $id";
```

El problema es que me da el siguiente Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la Base de datos lo tengo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes asignar el valor directo de null a tu campo de la tabla

prueba el siguiente ejemplo:

```
$sql = "UPDATE document SET date_session = Null WHERE id = $id";
```

o

```
$sql = "UPDATE document SET date_session = '".(($mod_date_session)?$mod_date_session:NULL)."' WHERE id = $id";
```